# How to join factors from different rows under multiple loops

Tags: mysql, loops, join

I'm trying to take a table that has columns (brand, name, id, time, price) and add to it in the same row the price at the time before, so the new column (brand, name, id, time, price, prev_price). In this price and prev_price are both integers.

The challenge I'm running into is that the database I'm working with has a host of different variables for each.
For example: 
brands A, B, C, D
name: 1 - 100 (each different for brand)
id: 80 - 300 (also each different for brand)

Example Table with brand and name held constant & what I would want the prev_price factor to contain

```
brand   name   id   time   price   prev_price
A         25    80   1       103       NULL
A         25    80   2       105       103
A         25    81   1       24        NULL
A         25    81   2       24        0
A         25    81   3       14        -10
```

Can anyone help recommend how to do this?

Comment: Where are you grabbing prev_price from? Are you grabbing that from another table? Or are you trying to somehow turn back time to find what the price was at an earlier time?

Comment: I'm trying to add the column prev_price where those would be the values in the table -- NULL if no first time entry and the value of price at t-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, try this:

```
Select mytable.*, x.price AS prev_price
FROM mytable LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM mytable) AS x ON
    mytable.id = x.id
    AND mytable.brand = x.brand
    AND mytable.name = x.name
    AND mytable.time = x.time + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first determine the previous `time` for each `(brand,name,id)` triple, then make a self-join on that time to extract the `prev_time`:

```
SELECT mytable.*, prev.price AS prev_price
FROM   mytable
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT   mytable.*, MAX(t2.time) AS prev_time
    FROM     mytable LEFT JOIN mytable AS prev ON
             prev.brand = mytable.brand
         AND prev.name  = mytable.name
         AND prev.id    = mytable.id
         AND prev.time  < mytable.time
    GROUP BY mytable.brand, mytable.name, mytable.id, mytable.time
  ) AS pairs USING (brand, name, id, time)
  LEFT JOIN mytable AS prev ON
        prev.brand = pairs.brand
    AND prev.name  = pairs.name
    AND prev.id    = pairs.id
    AND prev.time  = pairs.prev_time
```